# java8 check optional null value more then once

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

How do i write this in java8 in 1 line?

```
if (Optional.ofNullable(mapOfIntAndListOfObjects.get(spn)).isPresent()) {
    Date paydate = Optional.ofNullable(mapOfIntAndListOfObjects.get(spn).stream().findFirst()).get().orElse(new MyObject()).getPayDate();
    logger.info("paydate {} ", paydate);
    return paydate;
} 
return null;
```

Comment: You should only use Optional as a return type of a method. Using Optional as a replacement for if-else statement abuses the intent and makes your code less readable and adds completely unnecessary object allocations. https://blog.joda.org/2015/08/java-se-8-optional-pragmatic-approach.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
Date payDate =  mapOfIntAndListOfObjects.getOrDefault(spn, Collections.emptyList())
        .stream()
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(new MyObject())
        .getPayDate();
logger.info("paydate {} ", paydate);
return payDate;
```

You don't really seem to be in need of wrapping them around `Optional`.

Comment: Perfect `getOrDefault(spn, new ArrayList<>())` this is what i was looking for :)

Comment: There’s no need to allocate a new `ArrayList`; use `getOrDefault(spn, Collections.emptyList())`

Comment: @Holger Actually, there's no need to use either (assuming my answer is correct).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(mapOfIntAndListOfObjects.getOrDefault(spn))
  .map(List::stream)
  .map(Stream::findFirst)
  .map(MyObject::getPayDate)
  .orElse(null); // or whatever default to return in case nothing found
```

Entirely uses the `Optional` functionality as intended. ie no default lists/values needed anywhere (except for the choice of what to return when nothing found).

Comment: [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V)) accepts 2 arguments.